# display div tag in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to display the div tag in same line.Now empty div appear in same line.I have content in php while loop so having variation in display.
client box appear slight below from payroll div.[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ps8nda6n/)

```css
.pay{
  width:35%;
  height:450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
  margin-left:2%;  
}

.inner{
 position:relative;
   height:23px;
    background: #C0C0C0;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:13px;
   color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <div class="pay 1">
                       <div class="inner">
                           <h3>Payroll Documents</h3>
                           
                       </div>
     <a>hello </a><br>
     <a>hello </a><br>
     <a>hello </a><br>
                    </div>
      <div class="pay 2">
                       <div class="inner">
                           <h3>Clients Documents</h3>
                       </div>
                      <a>hello </a>
     
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just use "vertical-align:top" to ".pay" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Now the two divs are positioned in same link, check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ps8nda6n/3/
```

Answer (score 2):

add vertical-align: top; in your CSS 'pay' class property.

```
.pay{
  width:35%;
  height:450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:2%;  
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display:inline-block;` I have added `float:left` to bring the desired results.

Also add `<div style="clear: both"></div>` at the end of div's to clear the `float`

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ps8nda6n/1/)

```css
.pay{
  width:35%;
  height:450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-left:2%;  
}

.inner{
 position:relative;
   height:23px;
    background: #C0C0C0;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:13px;
   color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <div class="pay 1">
                       <div class="inner">
                           <h3>Payroll Documents</h3>
                           
                       </div>
     <a>hello </a><br>
     <a>hello </a><br>
     <a>hello </a><br>
                    </div>
      <div class="pay 2">
                       <div class="inner">
                           <h3>Clients Documents</h3>
                       </div>
                      <a>hello </a>
     
                    </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have need to add one extra css attribute(float: left;) in pay class.
Your pay class now become like below

```css
.pay{
  width:35%;
  height:450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:2%;  
  float: left;
}
```